# upip is not installed

Tags: software-installation, packages, pi-pico

I'm new to the pico world and micropython. Needless to say, one of the first things anyone should learn is the ability to set up environments and know the structure of the pico.

I have read the documentation for the package distribution process found [here](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/packages.html#packages). By the looks of it, `upip` should automatically be installed after dropping the UF2 file on the pico in the file explorer system right? I am using v1.19.1 found [here](https://micropython.org/download/rp2-pico/).

When I open an REPL console and run,

```
import upip
```

it throws `ImportError: no module named 'upip'`. Should this automatically be installed like `pip` is for normal python? This issue has been difficult to come by.

I will also add, however, I am not using the Thonny IDE, but am using PyCharm with a Micropython plug in. I am not sure if this should have any affect on this matter.

Comment: If you followed some instructions and they are wrong (I would double check that you have followed and understood the instructions) the thing to do would be to raise an issue with the instruction writer.

Comment: @joan The pico is working just fine. It still has the necessary modules, but `upip` is not there. Could it be the UF2 file? I haven't tried using any others.

Comment: Could it be that upip should be installed on your computer rather than on the pico?

Comment: How would you go about doing that? @NomadMaker

Comment: Sorry, I barely know any micro-python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understood, is `upip` replaced by `mip` in the 1.19 release of micropython. https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/packages.html

Therefor you should go with

```
>>> import mip
>>> mip.install("pkgname")
```

Comment: Just tried it, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe you have to download the latest firmware: https://micropython.org/download/rp2-pico-w/

Comment: Well I was previously using 1.19.1, but the latest release from 10/14/2022, which is still 1.19.1 worked! I appreciate the help.

Comment: This one worked perfectly since I was not able to use upip in raspberry pico w.